# How would I query a query in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a query as follows:

```
events = Event.joins(:user_events).where(:user_events => { :user => user }).by_time(time)
```

How would I go about creating a query to find a specific object in this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `events` object is ActiveRecord::Relation object, which means it's chainable.

You can further call another condition based on it.

```
event = events.where(id: 123)
```

Comment: Do you know how I would get all of the specific id's of the events object?

Comment: Yes, `events.pluck :id`